# What is the behavior of writing a non-printing character in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, io, standards, undefined-behavior

Is the behavior of writing a non-printing character undefined or implementation-defined, if the character is written via `printf`/`fprintf`? I am confused because the words in the C standard N1570/5.2.2 only talks about the display semantics for printing characters and alphabetic escape sequences.

In addition, what if the character is written via `std::ostream` (C++ only)?

Comment: Give us an example of non-printing and non-controlling character.

Comment: @LP: to be pedantic, depends on the output device receiving the data.  A teletype will behave differently than a file or GUI Window or printer.

Comment: Moreover, the output stream might be `/dev/null`. Apparently it won't print even the "printable" characters.

Comment: @user694733 Do you mean all non-printing characters are controlling characters? Sorry that I cannot give an example, because in the common seven-bit US ASCII character set, it does.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well, right. Is what I meant, but my bad english kills another kitten ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of ASCII non-printable (control) characters is implementation defined.

Specifically, interpretation is the responsibility of the output device.

**Edit 1:**
When the output device is opened as a file, it can be opened as `binary`.  When opened as `binary` the output is not translated (e.g. line endings).

Comment: Formally, not "implementation defined" but implementation specific. In the language definition "implementation defined" means that a conforming compiler must document what it does.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this part of the Standard before; the wording is interesting.  If the Standard mandated that `\a` must produce a visible or audible alert, it could not be implemented on platforms that have no means of supporting such behavior.  If the Standard said that a `\a` must map to a character which produces such an alert on platforms where one exists, that could be seen as suggesting that platforms without such a feature should be judged "inferior".  To avoid either of those issues, it uses "is intended" language which I've not seen elsewhere, but could have been useful...