# c++ assigning the index of char array outside a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, char

Trying to figure out why my char array inside a class or struct does not accept all characters as it normally would do when not inside a class or struct.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;
struct A{
  char address[SIZE];
}

int main(){
  char address_from_main[SIZE];
  A a;

  address_from_main[2] = 9;
  cout<<"address from main: "<<address_from_main[2]<<endl;

  a.address[2] = 9;
  a.address[3] = 'a';
  cout<<"show 2: "<<a.address[2]<<" , but didnt show"<<endl;
  cout<<"show 3: "<<a.address[3]<<" , this one did"<<endl;
```

output = address from main: 9\nshow 2:  , but didnt show \nshow3:  , this one did

How is this possible? 
Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: `char` and `int` have different display... `9 != '9'`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/770a3b7e82bfa5c5) the first example. It doesn't output `9`.

Comment: anything.. but it is a constant bigger than the index. Say 100.

Comment: Did you maybe use `'9'` instead of `9` at some point and just forgot the `' '`?

Comment: @Jarod42 UB?? Maybe implementation defined.

Comment: Character value 9 is usually a tab character which - even if "displayed" - isn't visible because it is blank.

Comment: [It doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3de5b0fb87b02e3).

Comment: Yes your are right @nwp, actually it doesnt. In the rush I forgot to paste it in context of the array. anyway.

Comment: @liliscent: indeed, implementation specific according to [what-is-the-behavior-of-writing-a-non-printing-character-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41700322/what-is-the-behavior-of-writing-a-non-printing-character-in-c-c) and Not UB as I though. Moreover `9` is `\t` so printable in current case.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, as you said, that is working fine but that is impossible as the array you are declaring is a `char array` and you are storing a `numeric` value as `int value` in it.

```
address[2] = 9;//assigning a int value not a character
cout<<address[2]<<endl;// hence will not print 9 but some junk value

address[2] = '9';//Correct, assigning a numeric character
cout<<address[2]<<endl;// Will print 9
```

Also read about memory allocation for a integer and a character and see what is the difference between byte allocation for both.

Comment: Assigning `9` to a `char` isn't exactly wrong. `char`s can be used as 8 bit integers and implicit conversions to and from `int` exist, making this legal.

Comment: But if I would say this: 
char temp = 9;
address[2] = temp; 
and then cout<<temp 
I would get 9.
But the moment address is located somewhere else it wouldnt.?

Comment: @nwp, Not wrong I know that. But you are assuming it as character. Correcting my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Khamaseen, Did you tried? if your compiler is doing so it is strange.

Comment: @Khamaseen That doesn't print `9` either, it will print a tab.

Comment: @nwp, Yes if numeric equivalent of tab is 9.

Comment: No I tried, many times.. That is why I came here. Couldn't find anything on the web either. Using cygwin to compile. Don't know can be... 
I get the output of numbers when assigning characters. Using cygwin.. can be a compiler mistake then?

Comment: When not using an char[] but instead a regular char it indeed also gives me a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Guess having an unsigned char did the trick. Eventually.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct Frame {
  unsigned char total_frame[16];
  int length_frame = 5;
  int checksum;
  bool checksum_good = 1;
  bool complete = 1;
};



int main(){
  Frame total;
  // open a file in read mode.
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("input-file.txt");
  cout << "Reading from the file" << endl;

  //reading from the file
  for(int i=0; i<16; ++i){
    cin>>total.total_frame[i];
  }
  cout<<"read"<<endl;

  //reading out from the buffer to the screen
  for(int i=0; i<16; ++i){
    cout<<total.total_frame[i]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```